# IIS wont send e-mail with specific FROM header

Tags: php, iis, email

Can anyone please explain why IIS wont send message from php if FROM header field is in the following format:  `FROM: "Some Name" <email@address.com>`.  If I just use email@address.com everything is ok.

Comment: And isn't it "MAIL FROM:" not "FROM:"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's old and it relates to the TO header, but it may point you on the correct path.

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=28038